# WiFi randomly disconnects and can't find network

Tags: wireless, 18.10

I run Ubuntu 18.10, and sometimes after I've been using my PC for a while, my WiFi randomly disconnects and it can't find any networks. This continues even after turning it off and on again. The only fix is a restart. I have already disabled wireless power saving by setting wifi.powermode in default-wifi-powersave-on.conf to 0, and this continues. What is a way to debug and fix this error? I am relatively new to Linux.

Output of nmcli device:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
wlp6s0  wifi      connected    hi         
enp3s0  ethernet  unavailable  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

Output of ip addr show:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:9c:bd:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:4d:54:08:f0:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp6s0
       valid_lft 86152sec preferred_lft 86152sec
    inet6 fdc8:94bb:cc34:4600:2544:e37:c810:9016/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 6954sec preferred_lft 3354sec
    inet6 fdc8:94bb:cc34:4600:e0af:85f3:6239:1088/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6954sec preferred_lft 3354sec
    inet6 fe80::ca35:b176:9647:8489/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output for sudo lshw -short -class network:

```
[sudo] password for liaquore: 
H/W path                  Device     Class       Description
============================================================
/0/100/1.3/0.2/0/0        enp3s0     network     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.2/4/0        wlp6s0     network     RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Output for lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA":

```
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550/550X] (rev c7)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550/550X]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

Output for rfkill:

```
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

Output for ls -l /etc/resolv.conf:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 10 01:42 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Output for nmcli device show wlp6s0 | grep IP4.DNS:

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
```

Output for ls -l /etc/resolv.conf:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Apr 10 15:03 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92294/discussion-on-question-by-logan-wifi-randomly-disconnects-and-cant-find-network).

Comment: @Logan, you may join me for a chat session to solve the issue.